# How to exclude sky reflections from material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I need to make two objects on the same scene. The first object should have a sky reflections but the second should not. Is there a simple way to exclude sky reflections from one material but keep it for another? I use Cycles.

Comment: Yes, I didn't read that carefully enough. There are two answers to my question and one of them has a .blend example. Thank you.

Comment: Both answers works

Comment: Oh, wait, there are even three answers: 
the first is per-world
the second is per-material (it is in the comments of the first answer)
the third is per-object